# How to make a script executes every time a template is triggered into a JavaSrcript SPA Application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, single-page-application

I have a specific problem about executing a JS file into a SPA application.

So i have a JS file which runs an IIFE. I have a Single Page Application and i'm attaching the JS file with a script tag to the head of my index file.

My problem is that i want to run IIFE every time when i go to a specific template page. To do this i have to make the script executes every time this template is triggered by the client.  If the whole application reloads the IIFE runs ones and thats it. After that when i navigate through my templates and then go back to the one where i want the IIFE to work the script doesnt re-executes.

P.S. I tried to put JS file into a script tag directly into my template but it doesnt work. Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

Normally in te concept of a SPA application and depends on the frond-end framework you are using, your template is rendered after your routing code and which this one attach a template and a controller. You can execute your js into this controller at this beggining.

It will run every time it is called.